# Ресурсы по Python и Perl

Tags: python, perl

Существуют сайты или книги с заданиями/упражнениями по языкам Python и Perl? Если знаете такие ресурсы, то дайте ссылки. Мне необходимо практиковаться по данным языкам. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

лучшая практика - начать делать что-то реальное, а не исскуственно придуманные кем-то бесцельные задания.

Вы начинаете познавать язык для чего? У вас есть какая-то цель? Или просто так, "на будущее"? Если первое, то вперед. Если второе, забросьте и ждите пока не появиться цель

Answer (score 1):

[Perl 5 version 14.1 documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/) - лучше не найдете по Perl

Comment: Не теория нужна, а задания/упражнения и желательно с ответами! Чтобы тренироваться!

Answer (score 1):

«[Есть больше одного метода сделать это](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMTOWTDI)» — девиз перла. Как результат — у задания/упражнения на перле будет несколько правильных ответов.

[Антон Шевцов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3274/anton-shevtsov) вам ответил, что лучшая практика — начать делать что-то реальное. В этом он, безусловно прав. Для чего вам перл? Если перед вами стоит конкретная задача (например, средствами перла сделать выборку из огромного лог-файла и что-нибудь вычислить по ней) — решайте именно такую конкретную задачу. Понятно, что результат первого подхода к задаче не будет идеальным — не страшно: вам можно будет ставить перед собой следующие цели (например, сделать код компактнее/быстрее/удобочитаемее) и достигать их.

По своему опыту программирования (больше десятка языков плюс куча библиотек к ним — за более чем 20 лет) могу сказать, что такой подход — решение конкретных задач — вполне работоспособен. С другой стороны, бесцельное решение упражнений (лишь бы порешать) мало что даёт.

Answer (score 1):

лучшая практика - начать делать что-то реальное, а не исскуственно придуманные кем-то бесцельные задания.

совершенно с этим не согласен - вы же в первом классе не начинаете читать сразу Войну и мир Толстого или Гамлета в оригинале, а начинаете с азов, с букв в букваре, как строятся предложения и т.д. Так и здесь, нужен хороший учебник. Могу посоветовать книги по Perl:

Шварц Р., Феникс Т., брайан д фой - Изучаем Perl, 5-е издание
Шварц Р., Фой Б., Феникс Т. - Perl. Изучаем глубже. 2-е издание
Ларри Уолл, Том Кристиансен, Джон Орвант - Программирование на Perl
Кристиансен Т., Торкингтон Н. - Perl. Сборник рецептов. Для профессионалов

Есть еще много книг, в основном на английском. Но эти самые лучшие для новичка. 
Советую начать именно с книги "Программирование на Perl". Хотя бы введение и 2 главы. Стиль данной книги не предполагает выполнение упражнений, но рассказывает, почему этот язык создавался и зачем он нужен. Потом можно переходить к книге "Изучаем Perl", а далее - к книге "Perl. Изучаем глубже". Там есть примеры.

Answer (score 0):

[Учебник Python 2.6](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_Python_2.6)

Comment: А где там упражнения? Нужны реальные задания/упражнения с ответами в случае затруднения в решении.

Answer (score 0):

http://szabgab.com/perl_tutorial.html туторы от Gabor'a Szabo
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_Programming/ простенькие задачки с решениями
http://projecteuler.net/ куча задачек которые хорошо решать програмным кодом и проверять верность решения.

https://bitbucket.org/shlomif/project-euler/src/810af966a391/project-euler/ решения для первых N задач projecteuler написанные Shlomi Fish, автором [многих модулей на CPAN](https://metacpan.org/author/SHLOMIF)
http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/ возможность решить задачу и отправить на выполнение

Книги "Learning Perl" и "Beginning Perl" содержат некоторое количество упражнений.

Некоторые ссылки взяты [отсюда](http://perl-begin.org/exercises/)